# How to handle errors that don't have any HTTP codes in a Flask app?

Tags: python, http, flask, jinja2

My Flask app takes input data from the user and performs some ML operations on them. Sometimes, the input given by the user is not correct so, it throws errors. Now, I have tried to make my code more robust so as to handle the values well but sometimes, it ends up showing up some value/type errors like:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U16') dtype('<U16') dtype('<U16') 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list' 

ValueError: Unable to parse string " " at position 488
```

These are usually accompanied by HTTP status code 500, but all these errors are for different causes. Is there any way I can handle and convey the exact error message to the user in a proper way?

Comment: A HTTP response will always have a status code.

Comment: @narendra-choudhary My apologies. I have edited the question as there is a new predicament now. How do I know which exact error is being thrown and how do I convey the same to the user? Because all 3 errors in my question have the same status code 500.

Comment: There are standard response code for some standard errors. For client's mistakes, 4xx status codes are used. Say client sent request data which can't be processed by server, usually 422 is the response code. Since [not all codes in 4xx, and 5xx are defined in the standard RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10), you can roll out your own custom codes are well. But make sure to publish them to users, so that they know the contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must implement an error handler that catch your specific exceptions and return whatever http error you want (with message)

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/

In you case you might want to return a 400 bad request